# Ocean Modifier Unique Texture

Tags: ocean-simulation

I'm creating a large ocean with the Ocean Modifier for a still render. I need the ocean to be fairly choppy but find that the only way I can get it fairly choppy is if I repeat the texture 5 time in both X and Y direction as per image below.

[image]

This makes the texture look very repetitive. Is there a way that I can create a large size ocean with lots of choppy waves that are not an exact repeat?

Comment: Perhaps you can break repetition a little with a displacement modifier on top of the ocean simulation